# PHP MySQL IPN Problem

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm using a PayPal IPN script to process subscription payments on my new project. Everything seems to work great but for some reason when the payment is processed and accepted my databases just don't update.

This is the part of the IPN script to update my databases:

```
$p->add_field('cmd','_xclick-subscriptions');
$p->add_field('no_note','1');
$p->add_field('currency_code','USD');
$p->add_field('a3', "0.01");
$p->add_field('t3', "M");
$p->add_field('p3', "1");
$p->add_field('src', "1");
$p->add_field('sra', "1");
$p->add_field('business', "myemail@gmail.com");
$p->add_field('return', "http://myurl.com/");
$p->add_field('cancel_return', $this_script.'?action=cancel');
$p->add_field('notify_url', $this_script.'?action=ipn');
$p->add_field('item_name', "My Package Thing ($_POST[hash])");
$p->add_field('custom', "$_POST[hash]");

$p->submit_paypal_post();
      //$p->dump_fields();
      break;
    case 'success':
      echo "<html><head><title>Success</title></head><body><h3>Thank you for your order.</h3>";
      echo "</body></html>";
      break;
    case 'cancel':
      echo "<html><head><title>Canceled</title></head><body><h3>The order was canceled.</h3>";
      echo "</body></html>";
      break;
    case 'ipn':
if ($p->validate_ipn()) {
include("config.php");
$select = mysql_query("UPDATE `mydb_accounts`.`accounts` SET `active` = '1' WHERE `accounts`.`hash` = '$_POST[hash]';") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query($select);
} break; }
```

`$_POST[hash]` works fine because when the "PayPal Payment Page" appears it's shown the item description.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: since the file is usually hit by paypal not a human make suer your logging errors to a file.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Any thoughts on a solution?

Comment: your not getting an error from mysql?

Comment: I don't believe I'm getting any error to be honest.

Comment: That would rely on you giving us any errors.  Specifically, try adding a quick line to email yourself mysql_error()'s results right after that function.  Also, keep the query in a variable and email yourself the query (with all variables dropped in).

Comment: looks like its failing "$p->validate_ipn()" so the query is never run

Comment: Try adding an else to email yourself there, or log the data somewhere that validation failed.

Comment: Good tip. I tried sending an e-mail but nothing was sent. I'm assuming it's failing then. Any thoughts?

Comment: to many blanks for me to even guess, whats the validate_ipn method do?

Comment: I believe it's what PayPal starts when  the payment has been received.

Comment: If you put emails in both spots, and your not receiving emails, chances are theres some sort of fatal error stopping the script from executing at all.  Add an email/logging feature on the first line, if that doesn't come through either, you've got a syntax error.

Comment: And you are right, thats what paypal calls when they receive payment.  You could also have an issue with the top half of the script, and paypal is simply not getting the IPN url and not knowing to call back.

Comment: Just to add to Matt's points above, PayPal PN validation requires you to send the `POST` data back to paypal in an identical format to that which is sent to you - It then verifies that it matches a message sent to you. Thus, any dummy or test IPN posts you make yourself will fail this check. Along with Matt's suggestions, try getting the script to log the raw POST data `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` in an email along with the `POST` data being sent to PP for verification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure that you mysql_connect in your config file (not only set database info).

Answer (score 0):

Having built a PayPal IPN handler three times (for different) systems I can confirm that most of the problems are caused by simple PHP syntax errors, or bugs that you can't see because the output of the script is lost.

**There is no point putting any output at all into the IPN handler - PayPal is the only thing that will see them and it discards them.**

My code is in two parts, the [payment callback](http://zxaf.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/zxaf/trunk/payment.php?revision=31&view=markup) and the [core logic entity](http://zxaf.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/zxaf/trunk/cbf/paypal.php?revision=24&view=markup). Always try opening the callback handler from the browser first to trap any syntax or logic errors. Then substitute the callback *POST* with a hardcoded test and see if it works. Then test against the paypal sandbox.

I use my Emesary notification system to send the messages to the backend - however you could append to a log file etc..